# Query help using Rank() or Row_Number() to deduplicate

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have a query that returns records from synchronized Data Extensions.

```
SELECT c.ID, 
c.AccountID, 
c.Email, 
c.FirstName, 
a.ID AS AccID, 
a.Name AS AccountName,  
p.Related_Agency__c, 
e.Tier__c, 
t.Name AS TierName, 
t.Status__c AS TierStatus,
e.Contacts_at_Location__c,
e.Reward_Amount__c,
FROM [Contact_Salesforce] c
    LEFT JOIN [Engagement__c_Salesforce] e ON c.ID = e.Contact__c
    LEFT JOIN [Account_Salesforce] a ON c.AccountID = a.ID
    LEFT JOIN [Tier__c_Salesforce] t ON e.Tier__c = t.ID
    LEFT JOIN [Program__c_Salesforce] p ON a.ID = p.Related_Agency__c
WHERE c.Focus__c LIKE '%PL%' AND c.Status__c = 'Active'
```

The query returns Contacts that may have different Contact IDs but the same Contact Email. What I am trying to do is dedupe the records by email address based on the highest Reward_Amount__c.

So if there are records like:

```
ID, ..., Email, ..., Reward_Amount__c
123, ..., abc@gmail.com, ..., 123
232, ..., abc@gmail.com, ..., 343
454, ..., def@gmail.com, ..., 234
```

I would like the result set to be:

```
232, ..., abc@gmail.com, ..., 343
454, ..., abc@gmail.com, ..., 234
```

Basically only adding one record of the duplicate email addresses with the highest Reward_Amount__c

I'm pretty sure I need to use the Rank() or Row_Number() function, but I'm not sure how to use it with all the other fields as well.

Comment: Why do you have two AccountID columns?

Comment: One is from Contact the other is from Account. I changed the fields a little for simplification. Does that matter? I can remove one of them.

Comment: It will throw an error if you try to return two columns with the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `ROW_NUMBER` function in a sub query select from it .

Try this:

```
SELECT 

c.ID, 
c.AccountID, 
c.Email, 
c.FirstName, 
a.ID AS AccID, 
a.Name AS AccountName,  
p.Related_Agency__c, 
e.Tier__c, 
t.Name AS TierName, 
t.Status__c AS TierStatus,
e.Contacts_at_Location__c,
e.Reward_Amount__c

FROM 

(SELECT c.ID, 
c.AccountID, 
c.Email, 
c.FirstName, 
a.ID AS AccID, 
a.Name AS AccountName,  
p.Related_Agency__c, 
e.Tier__c, 
t.Name AS TierName, 
t.Status__c AS TierStatus,
e.Contacts_at_Location__c,
e.Reward_Amount__c,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY c.Email ORDER BY Reward_Amount__c DESC) AS rank
FROM [Contact_Salesforce] c
    LEFT JOIN [Engagement__c_Salesforce] e ON c.ID = e.Contact__c
    LEFT JOIN [Account_Salesforce] a ON c.AccountID = a.ID
    LEFT JOIN [Tier__c_Salesforce] t ON e.Tier__c = t.ID
    LEFT JOIN [Program__c_Salesforce] p ON a.ID = p.Related_Agency__c
WHERE c.Focus__c LIKE '%PL%' AND c.Status__c = 'Active') x
WHERE x.rank = 1
```

Comment: I see the partition is c.ID...shouldn't it be Email? There can be different c.ID with the same c.Email. We only want the c.Email with the highest e.Reward_Amount__c. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In that case you can swap it will update

Comment: can you really use partition by clause in the Sql syntax supported by SFMC Query activities?

Comment: I havent touched marketing cloud in 5 years , but i dont see why they would take it out